# Find minimum and maximum of a long vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, element, min

I want to find both the minimum and maximum of a long vector. The following code works, but I need to traverse the vector twice.

I could use an old fashioned for loop, but I wonder if there is an elegant (c++11, std) way of doing it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     vector<double> C;

     // code to insert values in C not shown here

     const double cLower = *min_element(C.begin(), C.end());
     const double cUpper = *max_element(C.begin(), C.end());

     // code using cLower and cUpper


}
```

Comment: [A good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is always handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

```
auto mm = std::minmax_element(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
const double cLower = *mm.first;
const double cUpper = *mm.second;
```

Note this assumes the range is not empty (as does your existing solution), else the iterator dereferences are [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also note this is not quite the same as your solution, as `max_element` returns the first largest element, and `minmax_element` returns the last largest element. E.g.

```
1 2 1 2
  ^   ^
  A   B
```

Where `A` is found by your solution, and `B` is found by mine. (This is for reasons of stability; [Alex Stepanov got the definition of `max` wrong in the original STL](http://stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf#page=63).)